# Como testar um status 500 com Jest no Expressjs

Tags: typescript, jest

Tenho uma aplicação onde estou tentando criar um teste simples pra melhorar a cobertura do código. Atualmente tenho uma rota que retorna um *health check*, como esta:

```js
import { Express, Request, Response, Router } from 'express'
import { MongoHelper } from '../../infra/db/mongodb/helpers/mongo.helper'
import env from '../config/env'

export default (_router: Router, app: Express): void => {
  app.use(env.app.healthCheckBasePath, (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
    /* 
    O "MongoHelper" é uma função que contém a instância do MongoClient na propriedade "client"
    Se verificarmos na documentação da própria biblioteca mongodb para node podemos ver que existe
    o método "isConnected" que retorna se está ou não conectado no banco.
    */
    if (!MongoHelper.client.isConnected()) {
      /*
      Aqui está a parte do código que preciso testar. Quando eu envio essa informação o Jest testa
      apenas a parte de código ".status(500)" quando deveria testar o ".send" também
      */
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    }
    return res.sendStatus(200)
  })
}
```

O meu problem aé que a cobertura de código diz que não consigo testar a linha 17 desse arquivo (que é exatamente a linha que conte `return res.status(500).send()`).

Alguém por favor tem alguma idéia de como posso melhorar minha cobertura de código e conseguir testar o método `.send` nessa linha?

Comment: Geralmente quando eu quero testar esta situação eu utilizo a técnica de fazer um mock do request. Nunca trabalhei com Jest, mas a lib que utilizo é o `nock`. Tem um exemplo da utilização em meu github, no repositório cotacao e tokenAuthDatastore.

Comment: Mas estou trabalhando com o `jest` e além disso precis testar o método `sendStatus`...

Comment: Não é necessário "mudar" sua ferramenta, o `nock` tem que ser utilizado em conjunto pra te auxiliar neste teste, vc não precisa deixar de utilizar o `jest`.